# Fatal Error when trying to run the basic sample of cloudinary

Tags: php, cloudinary

Can anyone point me to the right direction in using cloudinary? I tried their basic sample but I encountered the error below.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare cl_upload_url() (previously declared in C:\My site\melbourne-apartment-bookings\admin\cloudinary\src\Helpers.php:4) in C:\My site\melbourne-apartment-bookings\admin\cloudinary\src\Helpers.php on line 8
```

Answer (score 1):

This was an broken by a recent commit and has now been fixed. Please download the sample again, it should work now.